# Play Framework Java - update did not work

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, ebean

I'm trying to create a CRUD application in Play Framework 2.5 with PostgreSQL DB.

Everything works fine, without update. I tried to do in my DAO Implementation by using Ebean.

```
public void update(User user) {        
    Ebean.update(user);
}
```

And also in controller:

```
public Result editUserProfile() {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    Form<User> userForm = formFactory.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    User user = userForm.get();

    List<String> errorList = userService.checkIfDataExist(user.getName(), user.getEmail());

    if (!errorList.isEmpty()) {
        return ok(errors.render(errorList));
    }
    userService.update(user); // <----------- by Ebean
    //user.update();             <----------- by Controller

    return redirect(routes.EditUserProfileController.editUserProfileForm());
}
```

Comment: And what is the update error? What is the code generating the error and what is the error message? Your question is unclear about these details. Also, please post your `User` model class.

Comment: Thank You for answear, but I fixed it. I didin't have hidden input inside with userId as a value.